# ONNX to Keras Conversion

Tags: keras, onnx

I am using the following link for my implementation. https://github.com/nerox8664/onnx2keras/

when trying to execute the code i am getting following error.

```
k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, ['input']) 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_convt2keras.py", line 8, in <module>
    k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, ['input'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnx2keras/converter.py", line 80, in onnx_to_keras
    weights[onnx_extracted_weights_name] = numpy_helper.to_array(onnx_w)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: According to the documentation `# Call the converter (input - is the main model input name, can be different for your model)` Have you checked that? Maybe you have to use a different name as second parameter.